# Devise on Rails is making me log in after I've logged in and not letting me post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm creating a blog; and I've made it so only the user has the option to  post. However when I signed up and click the "new post" it tries to make me log in again. - and then it won't let me log in even with the the account I just made.

I'm fairly new to programming so any information you need me to provide on this problem let me know.

Thank you.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar_default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar" do %>
      <%= image_tag "logo.png", height: 50 %>
    <% end %>
      <div class="navbar header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bella Blog</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
          <% if admin_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'My Account', edit_admin_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_admin_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_admin_session_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: what is the error it is returning exactly when you try to log in again?

Comment: When I first select New Post on my nav bar it says "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."(Even though I'm already signed in. Then when I try and sign in it says "Invalid Email or password."

Comment: have you tried logging out and logging back in? Does logging out produce and error?  It seems something is out of sync.  How are you checking for the current user in the nav, can you post the code from your nav?

Comment: Done. :) It doesn't produce an error. I've tried logging out and logging in numerous times. I still it the same wall.

Comment: Ok so the Devise model you created is called Admin? If you do something like just output the admin id into the view do you get an id?  It is just a check but have you tried that, something like `<li><%=  current_admin.id %></li>` right about the admin check (or name or whatever value you want) just to check that the admins value is there.

Comment: This is my admin.rb model 

 class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end

Comment: so what happens when you output a admin value into the view?

Comment: btw thank you for your time Rockwell Rice. :)

Comment: Where do I put it exactly?

Comment: I just pushed to git; I can link you to my code if that'll help?

Comment: Anywhere you can see it, how about in th ed nav right as above the check

Comment: Sure as link will help

Comment: https://github.com/JamesRevan/Blog

Comment: Ok I do not really have time to dig through the whole thing and set all this up.  My guess is the issue is with your two Devise models.  Have you tried to output admin values in the view, it is the easiest, fastest test.  Along with the admin one I mentioned above, also try it with user and see if one or the other is getting output.

Comment: When I put the <li><%= current_admin.id %></li> line in my nav bar a "1" appears

Comment: Nevermind. I'm scraping it and starting again. Thanks for you time though.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have two models with devise devise_for :users and devise_for :admin
In the post controller 
Change this line

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!, except: [:index, :show]
```

to

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```